# How Can I Get index of a external mesh with Object info and Capture attribute - Geo Node

Tags: node-editor

**What I want to do:**
I want to get some random number using Noise Texture node. And in my case I need to give the Noise Texture Node different input value to randomize the output. So I use a Bezier's index as an input value.

**What I met:**
I still get same output(I got some Ico Sphere with same size).

**My question:**

- I guess I didn't using the Capture Attribute node properly. So how can I get Index of External Meshes?

Thank you for your patience.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work with object's info, but it works, if you convert it to mesh:

[image]

Comment: Splines should have indices (like everything else), you even point out the node that gives you the index of its control points (Spline Parameter). Did you mean to say they don't have *vertices*?

Comment: you are right, i changed my answer

Comment: thank you all! SO Kind of you.

Comment: please click on the checkmark left to the answer, which helped you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As is the case with [your other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/255217/how-to-get-normal-and-position-using-capture-attributes-node) about the *Capture Attribute* node, you need to use its *Geometry* output for it to have any effect. To take an attribute from an object and use it on another, you can employ the *Transfer Attribute* node instead. That doesn't support curves, so you would need to convert it to mesh first, then you can do *something*, like what's shown in the video below. Though, to be honest, what kind of logical relationship you'd have with that info and the affected geometry (Ico Sphere) is not clear to me—since you would get similar results without it as long as you're randomizing the values via *Noise Texture* in the first place.

[image]

Comment: thank you, its a way to solve my problem.