# How to get Normal and Position using Capture Attributes Node

Tags: node-editor

**Waht I do:**

1. In my case, I capture Index using a Capture Attributes, and then put the value to a Noise Texture. It works fine. You'll see the IcoSphere distorted.
2. And then when I change the Index to Normal / Position, I got a IcoSphere without distortion.

**My Questions:**

1. Why it works with Index but Normal&Position fails.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, your *Set Position* node is still linked to the geometry output of the first *Capture Attribute* node--which is getting the *Index* information but not doing anything with it. [As noted in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/capture_attribute.html), you need to use the geometry output of the *Capture Attribute* node you get the information from for it to have an effect.

[image]

P.S. You don't need the node at all here in this case, it's redundant:

[image]

Comment: oh, thank you. I really made a silly mistake. And still learn sth else from your answer. BlenderStackExchange answer anything I wonder, so nice of you guys.